# How do I a embed a variable css style in a VB.NET xml string literal?

Tags: html, css, xml, vb.net

I would like to add a variable data to a string literal WITHIN the HTML tag

```
Dim locationOfImage as string = "http://blahblah......" 
Dim xmlString = _
            <div style="background:url(" <%= locationOfImage  %> ")">
                <h3>Some text</h3>

            </div>
```

The above does not work,  I can't quickly determine how to do this? Is this possible.  I could achieve what I am attempting to do with a StringBuilder but want to use the xml literal if possible.

Comment: Xattrbiute may be that way to go?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384832.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="<%= String.Format("background:url('{0}')", locationOfImage)  %>">
```